# Client PC (Win7/Win8) cannot ping to VMware server (CentOS 8), but server can ping client

Tags: virtual-machines, httpd, centos8

first of all I'm not a networking technician, so my networking lingo is very much limited.

I'm trying to help my coworker with troubleshooting a problem. So far I only rely on using search engine to find English-language solutions, and I haven't got any for this one.

We're trying to setup a (I quote from him) "web server httpd" using a CentOS 8 running on VMWare (the original server machine is running Win 10 and not a server version). Currently, the CentOS is running this command:

`php artisan serve --host 192.168.xx.xx --port 8081`

After that, we tried to open the said IP with the port on the vmware CentOS's Firefox. It opens up the intended page. The exact same can be said when I open the same thing on the machine's original OS.

The problem right now is that we can't open the same IP on other PCs (run Win7 and Win10) that is connected to the same ethernet. Pinging the IP via cmd always gives `request time out`, let alone opening the IP address on a web browser.

What we're trying to achieve is to have the other/client PCs to be able to open up the VMware IP address and thus displays the web server we have. What we've tried so far are listed below, and they haven't worked so far:

- Turning off the server's PC firewall
- Stopping the server's VMWare firewalld
- Changing the VMware network setting from NAT to Bridged
- Turning off client PC firewall.
- Changing the IP address of the CentOS VMware to static.

What do we need to do to be able to get what we trying to achieve?

EDIT: just to be clear, the IP address written above is not the real one used, I replaced some number to `xx` here for privacy reason

Comment: Is the subnet that the virtual machine is on the same subnet that the host (Windows machine) is on?

Comment: Yes, the subnet on the virtual machine and the host is the same

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so eventually I got it to work myself...

What I did to finally get it working was:

- On VMware settings, I went into Virtual Network Editor and changed the settings for "Bridged". I changed the used adapter from "Automatic" to the corresponding adapter of the server PC.
- Changed the settings for the CentOS 8 to use Bridged.
- On the CentOS 8 VM, I went to the internet adapter settings -- since this is an intranet system, it was a "wired" for it.
- Clicked on the settings, and went onto the IPv4 tab, and changed it from Manual to Automatic (DHCP).
- Back on the terminal, I started up Laravel again with the `php artisan serve --host 192.168.xx.xx --port 8081` command, but now with a new IP that I got from changing the above settings. (Port is kept the same since it's the one I've opened via firewalld.
- Tried to ping that IP on other computer, and now instead of `request time out` I got `Destination Net Unreachable`. Nevertheless, I tried to access the IP + port on a web browser, and now the page we've been trying to access now shows up!